# Spring Cloud Gateway Server MVC- Can we use spring mvc with spring cloud gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-gateway

what is the purpose of Spring Cloud Gateway Server MVC.
Can it be use on the place of spring cloud gateway reactive.
If yes,Can someone provide me better example.
here is document I am refering to

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc.html

I am trying to make it work but not understand what is the issue.
here is my configuration.

```
    import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig  {

      @Bean
       public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http.authorizeHttpRequests(exchanges->exchanges.requestMatchers("/oauth/**","/login/**").permitAll())
         .authorizeHttpRequests(https->https.anyRequest().authenticated())
         .oauth2Login(withDefaults());
           return http.build();
       }

   

}
```

> here is my yml file

```
spring:
 cloud:
    gateway:
      mvc:
       routes:
       - id: service1
         uri: http://localhost:8081/
         predicates:
         - Path=/api/**
 security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          azure:
            client-id: dummy737373737373
            client-secret: dummypassword737373737373
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: '{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
            scope: User.Read
        provider:
          azure:
            authorization-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/dummypasswordtenantid/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
            token-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/dummypasswordtenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token
            user-info-uri: https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo
            jwk-set-uri: https://login.microsoftonline.com/dummypasswordtenantid/discovery/v2.0/keys
            user-name-attribute: name
```

server:
port: 9000

> here is my pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>swiss</groupId>
    <artifactId>manoj-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>manoj-gateway</name>
    <description>manoj-gateway</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0-RC1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->

        <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
-->
        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

> I have one more spring boot service running on 8081.
> I need to redirect it to that service but It is not working.
> Can someone explain me what need to be change.
> thanks for the help
> I have made a change as suggested but I am getting following error and also removed spring security just to check of route is working properly.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.handler.RestClientProxyExchange$$Lambda$906/0x000000080060f988 does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object exchange(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest, org.springframework.web.client.RestClient$RequestHeadersSpec$ConvertibleClientHttpResponse)' of interface org.springframework.web.client.RestClient$RequestHeadersSpec$ExchangeFunction.
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchangeInternal(DefaultRestClient.java:456) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultRestClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchange(DefaultRestClient.java:429) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.handler.RestClientProxyExchange.exchange(RestClientProxyExchange.java:40) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc-4.1.0-RC1.jar:4.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.handler.ProxyExchangeHandlerFunction.handle(ProxyExchangeHandlerFunction.java:106) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc-4.1.0-RC1.jar:4.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.handler.HandlerFunctions$LookupProxyExchangeHandlerFunction.handle(HandlerFunctions.java:94) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc-4.1.0-RC1.jar:4.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$ofRequestProcessor$3(HandlerFilterFunction.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$andThen$0(HandlerFilterFunction.java:58) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.config.GatewayMvcPropertiesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.lambda$getRouterFunction$3(GatewayMvcPropertiesBeanDefinitionRegistrar.java:172) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc-4.1.0-RC1.jar:4.1.0-RC1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$andThen$0(HandlerFilterFunction.java:58) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$ofRequestProcessor$3(HandlerFilterFunction.java:83) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$andThen$1(HandlerFilterFunction.java:59) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$andThen$1(HandlerFilterFunction.java:59) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction.lambda$apply$2(HandlerFilterFunction.java:70) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.support.HandlerFunctionAdapter.handle(HandlerFunctionAdapter.java:107) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.filter.WeightCalculatorFilter.doFilter(WeightCalculatorFilter.java:229) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc-4.1.0-RC1.jar:4.1.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.filter.FormFilter.doFilter(FormFilter.java:97) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-mvc-4.1.0-RC1.jar:4.1.0-RC1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, if you still encounter some problems feel free to send the error logs for debugging.

Comment: Can you please show all your project files and updated files. eg where you added your server.port property, updated yaml file and class files

Comment: Here is my project : link 
https://github.com/manojsinghsaun/sringmvctest

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Spring cloud gateway MVC is an alternative of Spring cloud gateway Reactive. They are both quite similar, the difference between them comes from the methods and classes they use - for example Spring cloud gateway Reactive uses the reactive approach thus classes such as `Mono`, `Flux`, `ServerWebExchange`, `GatewayFilterFactory` and `RouteLocator` to name a few while Spring cloud gateway MVC uses classes such as `RouterFunction` to define routes, equivalent to `RouteLocator`.

The following is an example of defining a route predicate and filter using both spring cloud gateway MVC and Reactive. The example below implements a route which will only accept request after a certain time has passed and later on modify the request by adding a request header `X-Trace-Token`:

**EXAMPLE USING SPRING CLOUD GATEWAY REACTIVE**

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator routeConfig(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
        .route(p -> p.path("/accounts").and().after(ZonedDateTime.parse("2023-12-06T19:03:47.789-05:00[America/New_York]")))
        .filters(f -> f.addRequestHeader("X-Trace-Token", "cd855f1a-0df3-4199-bc33-821dc797fc29")
        .uri("http://example.com"))
        .build();
}
```

`**SAME EXAMPLE USING SPRING CLOUD GATEWAY MVC**

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routeConfig() {
    return route("route_id")
        .route(after(ZonedDateTime.parse("2023-12-06T19:03:47.789-05:00[America/New_York]")), GET("/accounts"), http("http://example.com"))
        .after(addRequestHeader("X-Trace-Token", "cd855f1a-0df3-4199-bc33-821dc797fc29"))
        .build();
}
```

The full documentation for spring cloud gateway MVC and Reactive can be found in the link you described above.

**EDIT**

The gateway routes configuration defined should work fine. Some possible fixes are:

`1`. Define the gateway server port in your yaml config eg.

```
server:
 port: 9000
```

then make the request to the service on port 8081 using the gateway server port for example:

`http://localhost:9000/api/some_path`

will be redirected to the service on port 8081.

`2`. To define the gateway routes use `spring.cloud.gateway.mvc.routes` instead because you are using spring cloud gateway mvc.

`3`. The error might be caused by the security policies you defined in your spring security configuration hence preventing the gateway server from redirecting to the service, if possible try testing the gateway routes while you have disable the spring security policies to identify if this is the problem.

Comment: Can anyone have any idea?

Comment: In reactive spring cloud gateway, we can use default-filters:
 - DedupeResponseHeader=....., but for this mvc version, seem like can't be used any more.  Same for globalcors properrties

Comment: What was the reason MVC alternative was created? Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that Spring Cloud Gateway is not compatible with Spring MVC (spring-boot-starter-web). this is detailed in [How to include Spring Cloud Gateway in the official reference documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#gateway-starter)

As already suggested by the error message, you would need to remove the dependency on spring-boot-starter-web. You can list all your direct and transitive dependencies with the following command:

```
 mvn dependency:tree
```

This will reveal that spring-cloud-starter depends on spring-boot-starter-web. Once you remove the following lines from your pom.xml, your application should start up:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Note that `spring-cloud-gateway` is not compatible with `spring-boot-starter-web`

Another posible solution is to change application.properties file:

```
spring.main.web-application-type=reactive
```

You can check this stackoverflow post for more information:

[Spring Cloud Gateway; Spring MVC found on classpath, which is incompatible with Spring Cloud Gateway Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68587832/spring-cloud-gateway-spring-mvc-found-on-classpath-which-is-incompatible-with)

**Edit:**

Following the error it seems that it has to do with a utility object called ProxyExchange:

Spring Cloud Gateway provides a utility object called ProxyExchange. You can use it inside a regular Spring web handler as a method parameter. It supports basic downstream HTTP exchanges through methods that mirror the HTTP verbs. With MVC, it also supports forwarding to a local handler through the forward() method. To use the ProxyExchange, include the right module in your classpath (either spring-cloud-gateway-mvc or spring-cloud-gateway-webflux).

The following MVC example proxies a request to /test downstream to a remote server:

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewaySampleApplication {

    @Value("${remote.home}")
    private URI home;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public ResponseEntity<?> proxy(ProxyExchange<byte[]> proxy) throws Exception {
        return proxy.uri(home.toString() + "/image/png").get();
    }

}
```

The following example does the same thing with Webflux:

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewaySampleApplication {

    @Value("${remote.home}")
    private URI home;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> proxy(ProxyExchange<byte[]> proxy) throws Exception {
        return proxy.uri(home.toString() + "/image/png").get();
    }

}
```

Convenience methods on the ProxyExchange enable the handler method to discover and enhance the URI path of the incoming request. For example, you might want to extract the trailing elements of a path to pass them downstream:

```
@GetMapping("/proxy/path/**")
public ResponseEntity<?> proxyPath(ProxyExchange<byte[]> proxy) throws Exception {
  String path = proxy.path("/proxy/path/");
  return proxy.uri(home.toString() + "/foos/" + path).get();
}
```

You can expand more details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway-proxy-exchange.html).

Comment: I need to forward my request to other service please can you check the project.
https://github.com/manojsinghsaun/sringmvctest

Answer (score 0):

## My own understanding

Recently, I have also been using SpringCloudGateway to develop our own gateway product. According to my understanding of this official document, it is as follows:

The default underlying dependency of SpringCloudGateway is Spring Webflux. We know that Spring Webflux is asynchronous and responsive programming, and the programming paradigm is written using the stream paradigm;

So does SpringCloudGateway support synchronous gateways? It is officially supported, and the official website provides a corresponding solution, which is to switch the default underlying Webflux to SpringMVC to support synchronization;

Equivalent to SpringCloudGateway giving you two underlying implementations of gateway routing, one is asynchronous corresponding to Spring Webflux, and the other is synchronous corresponding to Spring MVC.

## examples:

### 1 pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.winning.gate</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvc-gateway</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2023.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

### 2 application.yml:

```yaml
server:
  port: 9098
```

### 3 com.demo.GatewaySampleApplication:

```java
package com.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

/**
 * @author xch
 * 2023/12/15 16:56
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewaySampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewaySampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

### 4 com.demo.SimpleGateway

```java
package com.demo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.function.RouterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.function.ServerResponse;

import static org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.handler.GatewayRouterFunctions.route;
import static org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.handler.HandlerFunctions.http;

/**
 * @author xch
 * 2023/12/15 16:52
 */

@Configuration
class SimpleGateway {
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoute() {
        return route().GET("/demo", http("http://localhost:8080/")).build();
    }
}
```

Above is all the code

### 5 Request Results

```java
GET http://localhost:9098/demo?ceshi=ceshi

HTTP/1.1 200 
date: Fri, 15 Dec 2023 09:23:37 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "code": 0,
  "data": "ceshi"
}
Response file saved.
> 2023-12-15T172337.200.json

Response code: 200; Time: 19ms (19 ms); Content length: 25 bytes (25 B)
```

The destination service address of the route is in SimpleGateway, you can change it to your own service

Comment: I encountered a JDK version issue while debugging the example. The reason is that I am using JDK8, but the underlying spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc 4.1.0  uses Spring Boot 3, so JDK needs to be raised to 17.

Comment: Now configuration properties don't support globalcors and default-filter key.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the [code](https://github.com/manojsinghsaun/sringmvctest) you provided and got the same error:

```
2023-12-16T16:07:30.395+08:00 ERROR 40097 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.handler.RestClientProxyExchange$$Lambda$942/0x000000080114bf28 does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object exchange(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest, org.springframework.web.client.RestClient$RequestHeadersSpec$ConvertibleClientHttpResponse)' of interface org.springframework.web.client.RestClient$RequestHeadersSpec$ExchangeFunction.] with root cause
```

According to the error message, the variable `exchangeFunction` is not implement method `abstract java.lang.Object exchange(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest, org.springframework.web.client.RestClient$RequestHeadersSpec$ConvertibleClientHttpResponse)`：
[image]

lambda implement method failed to override the interface method. Normally, there should be only one such method:
`public java.lang.Object org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.handler.RestClientProxyExchange$$Lambda$942/0x000000080114bf28.exchange(org.springframework.http.HttpRequest,org.springframework.web.client.RestClient$RequestHeadersSpec$ConvertibleClientHttpResponse)`.

The variable `exchangeFunction` is declared in `RestClientProxyExchange`:
[image]

The byte code of the `exchange` method is as follows:
[image]

[image]

You can solve this problem by redefining the type, copying `RestClientProxyExchange` from Spring's source code and defining it in your project:

[image]

Why is this? I use the same source code, can only compile the correct result and can not compile the wrong result:
[image]

Maybe only Spring knows the reason.